# Multiple UITextView placeholders

Tags: ios, swift, uitextview, placeholder

I'm trying to put in placeholders into my UITextViews, and found a solution here using this chunk of code:

```
func textView(textView: UITextView, shouldChangeTextInRange range: NSRange, replacementText text: String) -> Bool {

    let currentText:NSString = storyView.text 
    let updatedText = currentText.stringByReplacingCharactersInRange(range, withString:text)

    if updatedText.isEmpty {
        storyView.text = "Write out your story here!"
        storyView.textColor = UIColor.lightGrayColor()
        storyView.selectedTextRange = storyView.textRangeFromPosition(storyView.beginningOfDocument, toPosition: storyView.beginningOfDocument)
        return false

    }else if storyView.textColor == UIColor.lightGrayColor() && !text.isEmpty {
        storyView.text = nil
        storyView.textColor = UIColor.blackColor()
    }

    return true
}

func textViewDidChangeSelection(storyView: UITextView) {
    if self.view.window != nil {
        if storyView.textColor == UIColor.lightGrayColor() {
            storyView.selectedTextRange = storyView.textRangeFromPosition(storyView.beginningOfDocument, toPosition: storyView.beginningOfDocument)
        }
    }
}
```

It works, and I'm happy with it, but I'd like to apply it to other UITextViews in the same ViewController. How would I do it without creating a duplicate instance of the textView method?

Comment: You should consider using tags. Then in `shouldChangeTextInRange` you check which textView is, and set the correct placeholder text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `textField.tag`  in your `shouldChangeTextInRange` method.

Give tag to your `textField` of same `viewcontroller`. And use that tag into `shouldChangeTextInRange` method.

```
func textView(textView: UITextView, shouldChangeTextInRange range: NSRange, replacementText text: String) -> Bool {

    let currentText:NSString = storyView.text 
    let updatedText = currentText.stringByReplacingCharactersInRange(range, withString:text)

    if updatedText.isEmpty {


if (textField.tag==0)//
 {
   storyView.text = "Write out your story here!" // stuff
}
else if(textField.tag==1)//
 {
    storyView.text = "Example 2 "// stuff
}
   storyView.textColor = UIColor.lightGrayColor()
  storyView.selectedTextRange = storyView.textRangeFromPosition(storyView.beginningOfDocument, toPosition: storyView.beginningOfDocument)
        return false

    }else if storyView.textColor == UIColor.lightGrayColor() && !text.isEmpty {
        storyView.text = nil
        storyView.textColor = UIColor.blackColor()
    }

    return true
}

func textViewDidChangeSelection(storyView: UITextView) {
    if self.view.window != nil {
        if storyView.textColor == UIColor.lightGrayColor() {
            storyView.selectedTextRange = storyView.textRangeFromPosition(storyView.beginningOfDocument, toPosition: storyView.beginningOfDocument)
        }
    }

}
```

May be it will help you.

Comment: @allen  If my answer is helpful to you. Please give me upvote or mark as answer.